# Определить selected по value из input'а

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В общем есть у меня **input** и **select**, они связаны - значение **value** из **select** попадает в **input**.
При загрузке страницы с **input**'ом и **select**'ом, в **input**'е храниться значение, которые изначально было взято с **select**'а.. Вопрос заключается вот в чём.. Как сделать чтобы при загрузке страницу у **option** был атрибут **selected**, если значение **option** (value), равен с значением **input**'а (value)?
Прям дико буду рад, если предоставите код этого заклинания, желательно на JQ.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#select').on('change', function() {
    result = $('#select :selected').val();
    $('#').val(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Раз</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
  <option value="4">Четыре</option>
  <option value="5">Пять</option>
</select>

<input id="input" val="" type="text" />
```

Comment: Предоставьте сначала код своего заклинания, магии может потребоваться некоторая настройка под вашу ауру

Comment: @Утка, добавил код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("option[value=" + $("#inp").val() + "]").prop("selected", true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" value="111">
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="222">222222</option>
  <option value="111">111111</option>
  <option value="333">333333</option>
</select>
```

Comment: спасибо, прям то, что нужно!